# XPathException in invokeTransform running Saxon-CE example

Tags: saxon

I am trying to run the  Saxon CE example on the [IBM Developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-healthcaresaxon/index.html)
It raises this error:

`SaxonCE.XSLT20Processor 23:04:41.615
SEVERE: XPathException in invokeTransform: Either a source document or an initial template must be specified
http://localhost:8984/static/SaxonceDebug/7FFD07C49946B3F4B1DE49E72F7E85FA.cache.html
Line 876`

I can run other Saxon CE examples. Is this some API change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggest you need to supply a source document or an initial template.

Something like:

```
<script>
var onSaxonLoad = function() {
Saxon.run( {
    stylesheet:   "books.xsl",
    source:       "books.xml"
});
```

or 
    `<script type="text/javascript"> var onSaxonLoad = function() { proc = Saxon.run( {
                stylesheet: 'scripts/stylesheet.xsl', initialTemplate: 'main' } ); };
      </script>`

Take a look at:

http://www.saxonica.com/ce/user-doc/1.1/index.html#!starting/running

Comment: The sample has 
`<script type="application/xslt+xml" language="xslt2.0" src="cda.xsl" input="SampleCDADocument.xml"></script>`
 
Changing `input=` to `data-source=` got it running for me. 
Thanks for the link